# Poor performance doing anything on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, windows-server-2019

We recently moved our workstation from on-prem hardware to an off-prem virtual machine workstation. In both cases, we connect through Remote Desktop Connection. The workstation is running a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter virtual machine, Version 1809 OS Build 17763.2686. It has good specs: ~500GB RAM, 16 core CPU.

Within a day or two of any reboot though, the system becomes laggy and everything slows down. This includes typing (there is a delay before characters actually show up in any editor), running 1+1 in R can take several to dozens of minutes, navigating through folders in Explorer is slow, and so on. There are generally 3-5 people connected to the machine at any moment. There doesn't appear to be any improvement with fewer people logged on. The most common software running is RStudio and SQL Server. It sometimes appears that starting RStudio is what causes the issues, but I haven't been able to isolate it to just that.

Task manager does not show any high usage of CPU, RAM, disk, etc.

What else can I investigate for the cause of these issues? I have no idea how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: Does reboot fix the problem at least for some time? Have you looked in Task Manager, Performance tab, for both Memory or CPU overload ? Use Resource Monitor for more information is you see a problem.

Comment: @harrymc Rebooting fixes the problem for perhaps a day or two. Performance tab doesn't show any overload. The problem occurs even with CPU/Memory usage very low. I'll check Resource Monitor to see if there's anything there

Comment: Task Manager should be enough to show if there is a problem or not. Are you sure that the physical machine where the VM is installed has enough resources to support it? One explanation would be if the physical machine is swapping out to support your 500GB RAM.

Comment: @harrymc "One explanation would be if the physical machine is swapping out to support your 500GB RAM." That's an interesting idea I have not considered. I'll need to look into that.